# Compute if each row has a TRUE or is all NA

Tags: r

I have a logical matrix like this :

```
x = cbind(c(T,F,F,NA), c(T,NA,F,NA), c(NA,F,F,NA), c(T,T,NA,NA))
```

I need to know for each row if there is at least one TRUE, whatever the NA, except if all the row is NA.

The expected output for my sample is then `fun(x) => c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,NA)`.

**Is there any function that could achieve this ?**

Here are my tries :

`rowSums(x) > 0L` returns    `c(NA,NA,FALSE,NA)`

`rowSums(x, na.rm = T) > 0L` returns `c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)`

`coalesce(NA, F, F, T)` returns `FALSE` (so I cannot apply it on each row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do with two `rowSums` to create the `NA` for rows having only NAs

```
(NA^!rowSums(!is.na(x)))*rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE)>0
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

---

Or another approach is with `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, c(as.data.frame(x), na.rm = TRUE)) > 0
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE    NA
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect ! Could you explain the first formula a little ? I'm really curious about this "powered NA" !

Comment: @DanChaltiel  The `rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE)>0` returns a logical vector of `TRUE/FALSE` but it doesn't differentiate the rows where there are only NAs as it also returns FALSE`.  In order to change the last element to NA, we do the `rowSums` on logical vector i.e.TRUE for non-NA elements  `rowSums(!is.na(x))`.  The last element will be 0.  If we negate or use `==0` it returns a logical vector i.e. `rowSums(!is.na(x))==0`
Using `NA^` changes the TRUE to `NA` and FALSE to 1.  Multiplying by 1 on logical vector returns the value of logical vector while that with NA returns NA

Comment: Whoa, this is quite amazing o_O

Comment: The fact that `NA^1==NA` but `NA^0==1` is really good to know too